# Runnable Jar is not connecting to postgres database when used inside another Java Swing Application

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse, jar, process

The runnable jar gets executed and then the it waits to receive inputs from the user. While it is waiting, I can't use the jar application, it is not hanging but database connections are not working.

After giving inputs to the main program, it receives and as it got to the end of the program, it terminates itself. Till then I can't use the jar, only after the main program got terminated. I can use the jar.

I want both to run simulataneously.

Any ideas on this

**MRE Code** - Eclipse 2021-03

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    
    System.out.print("Started...");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<Path of my runnable jar>");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    in.readLine();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```its loading for long time. ``` ?

Comment: It is loading forever...

Comment: Is you code execution  on halt because of connection attempt to DB is not going through?

Comment: yes, it waits until the swing application is closed. The moment I close it, it starts to connect to the database and then the jar runs perfectly.